# C# : Search the "v" which may or may not occur in the end of the string

Tags: c#

So, I have a C# string input which can be either "ABCD12345678" or "ABCD1234" or "ABCD1233456v1" or "ABCD1233456v2" or "AVVV1233456v334" or "ABVV1233456V4".

I need to manipulate and remove the last may or may not be occurring "v"/"V" and get the result like :
"ABCD1233456"
"ABVV1233456"
"AVVV1233456"

Please help. If I use substring straightforward it works for only those where "v" occurs but throws exception for those where it doesn't occur.

Comment: So what code have you got that doesn't work? I suspect it's using `LastIndexOf`... so what does that return if "v" doesn't occur?

Comment: I am using  
ip2 = inputstring.Substring(0, inputstring.LastIndexOf("v", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)); 
which works only when there is v/V at end of the string like "ABCD2343v123" and  I get "ABCD2343" which is correct.
I need something to work for both case v/V occurs or not.

When input doesn't have v/V in the end then it throws exception.

Comment: What about something like "ABCVV12345".  Should that return the entire string as is or just "ABC", or is that case even possible?

Comment: @Akshay: So have you found out what value is returned by `LastIndexOf` if there's no match? How do you normally write code which does one thing if a variable has one value, and something else otherwise? Please put your code in the question, btw...

Comment: If input is ABVvv1234v13 I need last v13 removed only.. Its kind of version thing ..

Comment: I am out of office now.. Will try the solutions tomorrow.. I think george lica's answer should work..

Comment: so if there are at least two vv then you want to keep them?

Comment: I need o/p as ABCV1234 for input ABCV1234 and ABCV1234v133. So from  Alphabets-Numeric-Alphabets2-Numeric2. I need only alphabets-numeric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little confusing when you say *at the end* because the *v* isn't really at the end...
Anyway, what about *Regex*?

```
public static class VRemover
{
    public static string Process(string input)
    {
        var regex = new Regex(@"(?'util'[a-z]+\d+)(v\d*)?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
        return regex.IsMatch(input)
            ? regex.Match(input).Groups["util"].Value
            : input;
    }
}
```

You can validate with this test (NUnit):

```
[TestFixture]
public class VRemoverTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var inputs = new[]
        {
            "ABCD12345678",
            "ABCD1234",
            "ABCD1233456v1",
            "ABCD1233456v2",
            "AVVV1233456v334",
            "ABVV1233456V4"
        };
        var expecteds = new[]
        {
            "ABCD12345678",
            "ABCD1234",
            "ABCD1233456",
            "ABCD1233456",
            "AVVV1233456",
            "ABVV1233456"
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.Length; i++)
        {
            var actual = VRemover.Process(inputs[i]);
            Assert.AreEqual(expecteds[i], actual);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Caverna. That is what I wanted. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static string RemoveString (string input)
{
        var indexOf = input.LastIndexOf("v", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        if (indexOf < 0)
            return input;

        return input.Substring(0, indexOf);

}
```

Comment: This is incomplete, it only returns the part before the last V of for example "ABVV1233456V4", not the 4.

Comment: @Saragis Read Akshay comment please, it is correct! he don't want the 4 he want only ABVV1233456

Comment: @Saragis you're wrong, this answer is more correct than yours. I'm willing to bet you downvoted all the other answers too

Comment: @GeorgeLica It might break when the input is ABVV1244... For this input I need o/p as ABVV1244

Answer (score 0):

```
    private string ReplaceLastV(string input)
    {
        if (input.IndexOf("v", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0) 
        {
            int lastIndexV = input.LastIndexOf("v", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

            return input.Substring(0, lastIndexV);
        }

        return input;
    }
```

Comment: How is this going to work for the ones that start with "ABVV" and "AVVV"? - Same goes for the answer from @GeorgeLica

Comment: @Kevin Those seem to also have a v near the end.  It's not clear from the OP if the solution needs to handle v's at the beginning with none at the end.

Comment: @Kevin Well, it's just taking a substring from index 0 to index "last v" so I don't see the problem? As indicated in the OP he only cares about the last occuring V.

Comment: You're right, I hadn't noticed that both of those cases have a v near the end. If that is the norm, and I have no reason from the question to think it is not, then either solution I was questioning would work fine.

Comment: I need o/p as ABCV1234 for input ABCV1234 and ABCV1234v133. So from  Alphabets-Numeric-Alphabets2-Numeric2. I need only alphabets-numeric